# Does desired state configuration support specifying custom log field names for IIS server logs

Tags: powershell, iis, dsc

I have googled Desired State Configuration and checked the Microsoft site for information on specifying settings for IIS servers, specifically using DSC to make IIS servers STIG compliant. Unfortunately, I can't find many details specifically for IIS web server setting. Any recommendations or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for administration IIS use the follow link [iis administration cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=win10-ps) it's have examples and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the Custom Logging Fields name in iis you could use the below PowerShell command:

```
New-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name logfile.customFields.collection -Value @{logFieldName='testname';sourceType='RequestHeader';sourceName='c-ip'}
```

[image]